# What is causing this undefined value in my Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-i18n

I'm using Vuex and the Vue-i18n plugin in my app. I'm getting undefined on my non-reactive array that I want to share between the plugins. If I log the array in both files, the i18n file prints first (undefined) and vuex prints the array as expected after. This leads me to believe I'm referencing the array in the i18n plugin before the array is created in the store file. I've perused the import/export MDN pages and I believe my imports here are synchronous? That's the only other cause I can think of. [Here's the i18n plugin in question](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/)

My files are as follows

**main.js**

```
import store from '@/store'
import i18n from '@/i18n'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  i18n,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

**vuex**

```
export const tabs = [
  'tab1',
  'tab2',
  'tab3',
  'tab4',
  'tab5'
]

console.log(tabs)
```

**i18n**

```
import { tabs } from '@/i18n'

console.log(tabs)
```

Comment: import { tabs } from '@/vuex' ?

Comment: @PaulMel I guess it wasn't clear, the folder is `store`. All of the paths should be fine

Comment: But the const tabs is in vuex? and you are trying to import it from i18n...? That's what I meant. Was that it?